# Multiple Table SQL SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to get results from two tables (archive and projects as shown below) that have stipulations from two different tables. We want to get Designer, ProjectNum and total Amount from both archive and projects(which have the exact same fields). archive and projects have a field called customerEmail which I want to use to exclude anything in a different table called profiles(which as customerEmail) that has a customerStatus of "Cancelled". I also want to get change_total from another table called changeorder that has ProjectNum that is in common with archive and project.

I first used a UNION to get the project and archive to come together and added code that takes out projects that have "Cancelled"

```
 SELECT DISTINCT(designerName), 
        SUM(total), 
        SUM(amount) 
 FROM
 (
   SELECT DISTINCT(Building_designer) as designerName, 
          COUNT(DISTINCT(Project_Num))as total, 
          SUM(archive.total_amount) as amount 
   FROM `archive` 
   INNER JOIN profiles
     ON archive.customer_email = profiles.customer_email 
   WHERE profiles.customer_status != "Cancelled" 
   AND SUBSTRING(archive.Project_Num,1,2)=17 
   GROUP BY designerName 

   UNION 

   SELECT DISTINCT(Building_designer) as designerName, 
          COUNT(DISTINCT(Project_Num))AS total, 
          SUM(projects.total_amount) AS amount
   FROM `projects` 
   INNER JOIN profiles 
     ON projects.customer_email = profiles.customer_email 
   WHERE profiles.customer_status != "Cancelled" 
   AND SUBSTRING(projects.Project_Num,1,2)=17 
   GROUP BY designerName
 ) AS temp 
 GROUP BY designerName
```

I am trying to get totalAMOUNT from the table called changeorder. would it be best to do another join to include the table?

Here is an example of it working without adding it to this statement

```
SELECT SUM(DISTINCT(change_total))
FROM `changeorder` 
WHERE SUBSTRING(project_num,1,2)=17
```

Why i need to add the other two tables is it keeps track of things that are "Cancelled" as well. so I need to SUM up the change_total for all of the project numbers associated with each person

Comment: SQL is **much** easier to debug if you format it

Comment: Also, you don't need the `DISTINCT`s if you are going to `GROUP BY` the column anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware. I started coding from "Hello World" less than two months ago.

If I understood you correctly, you're looking for three 'sets' of data:
1) Designer, ProjectNum and total_amount from archive
2) Designer, ProjectNum and total_amount from project
3) change_total from changeorder

You would like to eliminate from the first two any case where the customer status is cancelled (in a different table).

If this is all correct, try:

```
SELECT a.Designer, a.ProjectNum, a.total_amount, 
        prjct.Designer, prjct.ProjectNum, prjct.total_amount,
        chgOrd.change_total
    -- the first two JOINs are to enable the WHERE later for knocking out
FROM archive a JOIN profiles prf ON a.customerEmail = prf.customerEmail, 
              projects prjct JOIN profiles prf ON prjct.customerEmail = prf.customerEmail
    -- then another (double) JOIN to link changeorder properly to archive and project
              changeorder chgOrd JOIN a ON chgOrd.ProjectNum = a.ProjectNum
                                  JOIN prjct ON chgOrd.ProjectNum = prjct.ProjectNum
 WHERE prf.customerStatus <> "Cancelled"
```

I hope I'm right that you can use the aliases created at the beginning of the FROM in the JOINs at the end of it.